# Android Toast widget with background

Tags: android, colors, background, opacity, toast

I'd like to know if there is a simple way to darken the app background when calling the Toast widget.

When activated, the Toast widget would be above a dark and transparent background and that background would disappear as soon as the Toast widget disappear.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Same story as you asked here
[Android Toast widget disable app buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723653/android-toast-widget-disable-app-buttons)

Set the background -> call the toast -> start a timer : when timer = finished set background back