# Android Toast widget disable app buttons

Tags: android, button, widget, toast

I'd like to know if there is a way that, as soon as the Toast widget is called and as long it is visible on screen, all the app buttons are temporary disabled.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a timer and disable the buttons when you call the toast and when the timer is finished enable the buttons.

Comment: But how can I detect when the Toast widget starts and ends?

Comment: @thomaus to show a toast you call something like this:
Toast.makeText(this, "Toast message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
It starts when you can the show() method of a toast, and ends after the duration you've set (3rd param in the makeText method).